# Why is Givens better than Householder?

Tags: matrices

When trying to transform only the lower triangular part of a matrix ( transforming only the even elements to 0), why is Givens recommended instead of Householder? Thank you!

Comment: @YoavKallus The question you link to is by the same user and I can't see any comments or answers. Moreover, the question you link to has a sparseness assumption while this one doesn't

Comment: @YemonChoi Seems to be an automatic comment the system puts in when I tag a question as a duplicate. I don't actually think it answers this question.